# $scope issue with angular-strap $modal on route change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-strap

I use angular-strap(http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) to display modal dialog from controllers like this -

```
myModal = $modal({
    scope: $scope,
    template: 'template.html',
    show: false,
    backdrop: "static",
    keyboard: false,
    persist: true
});
myModal.$promise.then(myModal.show);
```

The issue is that it breaks on route change.

Consider `template.html` with content:

```
1 + 1 = {{ 1 + 1 }}
```

When I open the modal from inside a controller for a route say `/screen1`,
it  displays `1 + 1 = 2`.

But now if I close the modal and go to some other route say `/screen2`
and click browser's back button to again go to `/screen1` and on reopen the modal, it displays
`1 + 1 = {{ 1 + 1 }}`

I don't know why the scope gets detached on the second occasion.(I don't see any JS errors.)

Thanks in advance.